# Navigation container refresh issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

```
function AppHome({colorMode, currentLang, restartApp}) {
    const default_scheme = useColorScheme()
    let [color_choice, setColor_choice] = useState(colorMode)
    let [lang, setLang] = useState(currentLang)

    const colors = {
        auto: color_choice === "auto",
        ...(color_choice === "light" || color_choice === "auto" && default_scheme === "light") ? LightColors : DarkColors
    }

    const Home = ({navigation, route}) => (
        <HomePage
        navigation={navigation}
        openPremium={() => {}}
        NavigationBar={() => {}}
        restartApp={restartApp}
        />
    )

    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider value={{lang, setLang}} >
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={colors} >
                <NavigationContainer>     
                    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
                    }} >
                        <Tab.Screen name={'Home'} component={Home} />
                    </Tab.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

In this code, when I update `default_scheme`by editing device theme or any other state, a rerender of NavigationContainer is triggered, and this is fine. However, when this happens, the tab screen refreshes COMPLETELY, and the page I am on loses every progress (e.g. something I wrote on a textinput). How can I prevent this effect?

If I check Home component and I add this code

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log("This log should appear ONCE.")
}, [])
```

the log appears when every refresh I talked about before is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You have a component definition of `Home` instantiated inside another component definition (that of `AppHome`). That means the component is not referentially stable and any rerender of `AppHome` will completely recreate the `Home` component, which will be unmounted and remounted entirely, losing all state in the process.

However, I see that your wish to do this is because `Home` needs access to `restartApp` which is in the context of `Home`.

**Option A**

Make `Home` a first class (referentially stable) component and pass `restartApp` through props by using the [`children` of `Tab.Screen`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen#children) instead of the `component` prop.

```
function Home({navigation, restartApp}) {
 return (
        <HomePage
        navigation={navigation}
        openPremium={() => {}}
        NavigationBar={() => {}}
        restartApp={restartApp}
        />
    )
}

function AppHome({colorMode, currentLang, restartApp}) {
    const default_scheme = useColorScheme()
    let [color_choice, setColor_choice] = useState(colorMode)
    let [lang, setLang] = useState(currentLang)

    const colors = {
        auto: color_choice === "auto",
        ...(color_choice === "light" || color_choice === "auto" && default_scheme === "light") ? LightColors : DarkColors
    }



    return (
        <LanguageContext.Provider value={{lang, setLang}} >
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={colors} >
                <NavigationContainer>     
                    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false,
                        tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
                    }} >
                        <Tab.Screen name={'Home'}>
                            {(props) => <Home {...props} restartApp={restartApp} />}
                        </Tab.Screen>
                    </Tab.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Note as per the docs you may also opt to wrap `Home` in `React.memo`:

> By default, React Navigation applies optimizations to screen components to prevent unnecessary renders. Using a render callback removes those optimizations. So if you use a render callback, you'll need to ensure that you use React.memo or React.PureComponent for your screen components to avoid performance issues.

But also see option B.

**Option B**

For performance reasons, it's recommended to use context rather than the above trick. The docs state (in regards to using `children`):

> You can use this approach instead of the component prop if you need to pass additional props. Though we recommend using React context for passing data instead.

I will refrain from going into specific detail, as creating a context and putting something in it like `restartApp`, and then pulling it out of a child component, like `Home`, is a common task that's [well documented](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext).

You would still break out `Home` as a separate component, but you would reference it with the `component` prop on `Tab.Screen` like before. `Home` would get `restartApp` from this new context you would create that wraps `NavigationContainer`, via the `useContext` hook, as opposed to a prop.